# USB virus scanner, live boot?

Tags: antivirus, usb-drive

So after spending the better part of the last two days trying to find a good alternative on Google. I finally gave up and decided to post this...

I work for a firm that is really into security right now, so we have orders to scan all USB sticks and stuff before moving them to another system. 
I was tasked with finding a good solution for this. I though it would be a good idea to use some antivirus via a live boot CD, that is closed and filled so that nothing can infect it. Didn't really find anything that did that though, except for a few "rescue cd" programs, those are more tailored towards HDD scanning though...
Some of them also don't have support for offline virus definition updates with is something that I need as the computer I will be running this scanner on can't be connected to the network in any way. And as we plan to update the definition database each week it has to be a easy to just write a new CD with the new update.
Anyone of you security guys that know of a good solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

TLDR; Need a solution that can scan USB sticks, preferably a live boot option.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic. But, the German computer magazine c't includes each year such a Linux Live-CD (which can be used as USB stick too) which includes several antivirus products inclusive updates for one year. See [here](https://www.heise.de/download/product/desinfect-71642) (in German) for details.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But if the Linux Live-CD contains updates for a whole year without the possebilty to manually update then I can't use it. As I need yo update the virus definition each week. But thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: It looks like that you did not understand me correctly. The CD does not contain all the updates for the next year because how this should be possible (they are not released yet!). You can manually update all the scanners, but only for a year. After this year updating the pattern might not work any longer.

Comment: Oh, yeah your right. Sorry slow Monday you know... Will check it out, thanks!